# Problems with Phonegap 3.4.0 and the Camera Plugin (iOS): CDVPlugin class CDVCamera (pluginName: camera) does not exist

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I have currently a big Problem with Phonegap and Plugins like org.apache.cordova.camera. They will not be loaded in my project.

I've found a lot of different answers here on stackoverflow:
- reinstall plugins
- delete the platform and rebuild the project
- create a whole new project

and some more, but nothing has solved my problem.

This is the message I've found in the console.log:

```
2014-03-29 15:08:19.123 Parking[31170:70b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-03-29 15:08:19.132 Parking[31170:70b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-03-29 15:08:19.149 Parking[31170:70b] CDVPlugin class CDVLocation (pluginName: geolocation) does not exist.
2014-03-29 15:08:19.150 Parking[31170:70b] [CDVTimer][geolocation] 0.471950ms
2014-03-29 15:08:19.150 Parking[31170:70b] CDVPlugin class CDVCamera (pluginName: camera) does not exist.
2014-03-29 15:08:19.150 Parking[31170:70b] [CDVTimer][camera] 0.374973ms
2014-03-29 15:08:19.151 Parking[31170:70b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 1.603007ms
2014-03-29 15:08:19.247 Parking[31170:70b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
```

And this is the way I've added the plugins:

```
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

In my config.xml I've added the following parts:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
```

In my project I've used the camera example code from their docs, but navigator.camera was undefined.

Can anyone help me with this problems?

Comment: which folder that contain config.xml you add? there are two. the important one is in staging folder, not the outside one.

Comment: My config.xml is in: ProjectFolder/www/config.xml - Is that the correct config.xml ?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, I've tried Cordova instead of Phonegap - Cordova doesn't has these problems and worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

If your app  has spaces in the config.xml file, try removing them. Remove the plugins and remove the platform.  Then add the platform and re-install the plugins.  Thanks to user Aras this processes solved my problems.  [Plugin not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792101/plugin-not-found-or-is-not-a-cdvplugin-check-your-plugin-mapping-in-config-xml)

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Xcode make sure that the Camera plugin files are actually added to the project.

Select the file `CDVCamera.m` in the file browser to the left, then make sure that the checkbox next to your App in the Target Membership panel is checked. It wasn't in my case.

Repeat for `CDVJpegHeaderWriter.m` and `UIImage+CropScaleOrientation.m`.

You may have to add `ImageIO.framework` and `CoreLocation.framework` as well.